# How to order by blog ID in this multisite 'List Blogs' custom function

Tags: multisite, wpdb, order

I found this really cool function to list all the blogs on a multisite network install.

Because the original [multisite list blogs function](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_list) was depreciated :/

So I am using this function below which is great because it is so flexible.

But the only thing I can't seem to work out is how to re-order the get_results query. Can any one please help me understand how to re-order this query by blog id, instead of the current outputted alphabetical order.

```
function projects_menu($link_self = true)
{
    global $wpdb;
    echo '<ul class="nav nav-list">';

    $blogs = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT blog_id
        FROM {$wpdb->blogs}
        WHERE site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}'
        AND spam = '0'
        AND deleted = '0'
        AND archived = '0'
        AND blog_id != 1
    ");
    $sites = array();
    foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
        $sites[$blog->blog_id] = get_blog_option($blog->blog_id, 'blogname');
    }
    natsort($sites);
    foreach ($sites as $blog_id => $blog_title) {
        projects_menu_entry($blog_id, $blog_title, $link_self);
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Source of this functions https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/1966341

Thanks in advance.

---

See this should work but does not...

```
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT blog_id
        FROM {$wpdb->blogs}
        WHERE site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}'
        AND spam = '0'
        AND deleted = '0'
        AND archived = '0'
        AND blog_id != 1
        ORDER BY blog_id
    ");
```

---

```
// EVENTS SITEMAP
function projects_menu_entry($id, $title, $link_self)
{
    global $blog_id;
    if ($link_self || $id != $blog_id) {
        if ($id == $blog_id) {
            echo '<li class="active">';
        } else {
            echo '<li>';
        }
        $url = get_home_url($id);
        if (substr($url, -1) != '/') {
            // Note: I added a "/" to the end of the URL because WordPress
            // wasn't doing that automatically in v3.0.4. YMMV.
            $url .= '/';
        }
        echo '<a class="notranslate" href="' . $url . '"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> ' . $title . '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
function projects_menu($link_self = true)
{
    global $wpdb;
    echo '<ul class="nav nav-list">';
    echo '<li class="nav-header">Admin sitemap</li>';

    $query = "
    SELECT blog_id
    FROM $wpdb->blogs
    WHERE site_id = %d
       AND public   = '1'
       AND archived = '0'
       AND mature   = '0'
       AND spam     = '0'
       AND deleted  = '0'
       AND blog_id != '1'
    ORDER BY blog_id ASC";
    $blogs = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( $query, $wpdb->siteid ) );

    $sites = array();
    foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
        $sites[$blog->blog_id] = get_blog_option($blog->blog_id, 'blogname');
    }

    foreach ($sites as $blog_id => $blog_title) {
        projects_menu_entry($blog_id, $blog_title, $link_self);
    }

    projects_menu_entry(1, 'Home', $link_self);

    echo '</ul>';

}
```

Please see above my function 'trying' to list all blogs in on my network site and show which is currently being viewed by having a active class.

But the above code is only returning one site. And the home link.

Comment: Just add `ORDER BY blog_id` to the SQL query.

Comment: I just tried this and its not working... 
`$blogs = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT blog_id
        FROM {$wpdb->blogs}
        WHERE site_id = '{$wpdb->siteid}'
        ORDER BY blog_id
        AND spam = '0'
        AND deleted = '0'
        AND archived = '0'
        AND blog_id != 1
    ");`

Comment: Add it to the end.

Comment: Ok I tried this originally and still not work see my code above... Just is still alphabetical. I can't figure it out. I wonder why I got -1 on this question.

Comment: Posted my code above - definitely does not work.

Comment: @toscho - it's valid wordpress based question - why you close it?

Comment: I have closed it because I see it _still_ as plain SQL. Anyway, we want to help you, so I will reopen it for. Maybe someone finds a solution that works.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate it. Though I see what you mean about it being a more a programming issue. Though this post also appears on stackoverflow does it not?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a separate site. I will look into your problem this evening if no one else jumps in. I am pretty sure there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following query works. Note the quotes in `AND blog_id != '1'`

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
SELECT blog_id
FROM $wpdb->blogs
WHERE site_id = %d
    AND public   = '1'
    AND archived = '0'
    AND mature   = '0'
    AND spam     = '0'
    AND deleted  = '0'
    AND blog_id != '1'
ORDER BY blog_id ASC";
$blogs = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( $query, $wpdb->siteid) );
```

Result in a multi-site with three sites:

```
blogs = array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => '3',
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It only seems to return the one blog? Which is no6. And I have nine. They are definitely public too. Hmmm this is strange and you tested it to :/

Comment: @Joshc Disable all plugins and switch to Twenty Twelve. Then test just this snippet again.

Comment: See my updated question with your code. I think your just query may work with my nav list fuction. Sorry for not posting my full code orginally, I thought that just a $blogs query change would fix. But I think there maybe code problems as your query works fine on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am going to try and build a new fucntion but if you see a quick fix my existing function please let me know. Thanks